# k-means++ vs random for initial centers

Tags: algorithm, opencv, cluster-analysis, k-means, vlfeat

I've seen that in many K-means implementations, like [VLFeat k-means](http://www.vlfeat.org/api/kmeans.html) or [OpenCV k-means](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_ml/py_kmeans/py_kmeans_opencv/py_kmeans_opencv.html), there are essentially 2 methods for choosing starting centroids:

1. Randomly
2. Following the [K-Means++](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means%2B%2B) algorithm

However, I didn't get in which cases one is better of the other, especially because the starting method is considered important. Can you help me understanding this point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In theory, k-means++ is much nicer. It is a biased random sampling that prefers points that are farther from each other, and avoids close points. Random initialization may be unlucky and choose nearby centers.

So in theory, k-means++ should require fewer iterations and have a higher chance of finding the global optimum.

However, k-means++ is not exactly "free", and in my experiments I did not see any systematic difference between the two with the more advanced k-means algorithms. k-means++ requires O(k n) computation - about the cost of one full iteration. But there are improved k-means algorithms that iterate in much less than that. With these algorithms, k-means++ may cost some 10-20% of the total runtime (with textbook k-means it's often less than 1%).

I guess I prefer the simple random initialization now, try multiple times, give each try 10 iterations to refine on a sample, and then continue with the best only.

Comment: Could you  please give a look to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38512158/image-retrieval-through-fisher-vectors-why-my-implementation-works-so-bad) question?